# res.render options parameters error

Tags: node.js, parameters, express, pug

I'm using Node.js, Express and Jade.
I use res.render with many parameters I send to the .jade page that is going to be opened:

```
res.render('home', { title: '/home' , css: '/stylesheets/home.css', myvar:'false', myvar2:'notTrueOrFalse'});
```

into the .jade page I use those values, but if I use one of them into a javascript script it doesn't work, except it is a value like "false" or "true".
The console says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: notTrueOrFalse is not defined" Why?

This is the .jade file:

```
extends layout

block content   
#contenitore
    script.
        alert(#{myvar})     //THIS WORK
        alert(#{myvar2})    //THIS DOESN'T WORK
        var valore=checkAutentication(#{myvar})   //THIS WORK
        var valore=checkAutentication(#{myvar2})   //THIS DOESN'T WORK
        alert(#{title})      //THIS DOESN'T WORK
    #titolo
        p #{title}          //OUT OF THE SCRIPT THIS WORK
```

For the "title" variable the console says: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /"

What's the problem? Why can't I use variables passed with res.render into a script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take a moment and look at your jade. We'll convert it to HTML by replacing variables.

```
alert(false);
alert(notTrueOrFalse);
```

`alert(false)` works because it is treated as a boolean. But without quotes `notTrueOrFalse` is treated as a variable. So undefined variable error.

Try

```
alert("#{myvar2}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(#{myvar2})
```

Will be send to the client as:

```
alert(notTrueOrFalse);
```

Since it should be a string rather than a variable, this fails. The solution should be to surround it with quotes:

```
alert("#{myvar2}")
```